# Ratio of heights of a sphere, over and under water

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

When a sphere is floating in the water, only 10 % of the volume is above the surface, while the rest is below. I need to calculate the relationship between height for the part above, and below the water.
The solution in the textbook is 0.244

[image]

[image: Altered solution]
Thank you for all the feedback, however, I am still getting wrong answers as for H and h. Is there something else that I am doing wrong here

Comment: You need a formula for the partial volume in terms of $h$ in your diagram. I mean the volume of the part of the sphere which is between the horizontal plane at height $h$ and the top of the sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Part above the water is known as [Spherical Cap](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html) with known formulae for the volume.

The total Diameter is $D=h+H$ & $r=(h+H)/2$

Plug this into the Spherical Cap Volume formula and equate it to 10% of total volume. Solve this Equation in terms of $h/H$.

If the solution in the textbook is correct, you should get $h/H=0.244$ , else Post a comment here.

Alternatively, you can [verify](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1223382199) your answer yourself.

UPDATE:
Working out the Solution:

Volume of Spherical Cap : $(1/3) \Pi h^2 (3r-h)$ = $(1/3) \Pi h^2 (3(h+H)/2-h)$ = $(1/3) \Pi h^2 (3h/2+3H/2-2h/2)$ = $(1/3) \Pi h^2 (h/2+3H/2)$

Volume of Sphere is: $(4/3) \Pi r^3$ = $(4/3) \Pi (h+H)^3/8$ = $(1/3) \Pi (h+H)^3/2$

Hence:
$(1/3)\Pi h^2 (h/2+3H/2) = (0.1) (1/3) \Pi (h+H)^3/2$
$(1/3) h^2 (h/2+3H/2) = (0.1) (1/3) (h+H)^3/2$
$h^2 (h/2+3H/2) = (0.1) (h+H)^3/2$
$h^2 (h+3H) = (0.1) (h+H)^3$

Divide though-out by $H^3$
$h^2 (h+3H)/H^3 = (0.1) (h+H)^3/H^3$
$(h/H)^2 (h/H+3H/H) = (0.1) (h/H+H/H)^3$
$(h/H)^2 (h/H+3) = (0.1) (h/H+1)^3$

Let $h/H=X$
$X^2 (X+3) = (0.1) (X+1)^3$
Solve this.

Check whether $h/H = X = 0.244$ is valid.
$(0.244)^2 (0.244+3) = (0.1) (0.244+1)^3$
We get $ (0.193134784)$ & $(0.1) (1.925134784) $

Comment: Can I ask which program you use for calculating more extensive expressions like this one? I find GeoGebra quite helpful but I feel like it has its limitations. As for this problem, GeoGebra does not successfully run

Comment: You should try Exploring https://www.wolframalpha.com/ , Matlab , Scilab , Etc !!

Comment: I'm getting 0.24 as one of the solutions in WolframAlpha, but the issue is that there are many other solutions given when the calculations are run. How did you get 0.244?

Comment: Did you get the Equation mentioned in the Answer , having $h$ & $H$ or $(h/H)$ ? You should Post that Equation. I got 0.244 from your Q itself !

Comment: I just posted the equation and one of the solutions

Comment: Well, where did you Post it ? I can not see what you Posted !

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4485499/solution-to-the-ratios-of-heights-of-a-sphere

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about that , @Andrei , I think "Multiple Questions" about same "Issue" will make things become muddled !!

Comment: According to the Image Posted on the other Post, (which should actually be Posted here, by editing the Q !) there is a Problem in Input 7 (which user Andrei has Identified correctly) and that should be corrected to get the correct answer ; @Aristarchus_ ; LHS Parenthesis should be $(3H+3h)/2 - h$ which will **not** have $(h^2)$ ; It should become $(3H+h)/2$ ; Now you can divide through-out by H to get $(h/H)$ everywhere ; Change that to $X$ and solve for $(h/H)$ or $X$ ...

Comment: @Prem; @Andrei; I have edited in the corrected solution, which still seems to be wrong...

Comment: Thank you @Prem; your calculation is better than that of a computer!

Comment: But I used a computer to calculate that !!! @Aristarchus_

Comment: Then, I guess your calculation skills on a computer are exceptional. Can I know which program you are using? @Prem;

Comment: I used only "Windows Calc" & "MS Excel" !!! @Aristarchus_

Answer (score 2):

From the spherical cap of unit radius the volume formula is

$$ \pi h^2 (R-h/3)= ( 0.1 ) \frac43. \pi.1^3 \to \frac{0.4}{3}=h^2(1-h/3) $$

The cubic equation solves to ( two other real solutions are unacceptable) $$h\approx 0.3916,\; H= 2-h\approx 1.6084, \; \frac{h}{H}\approx 0.243472 ;$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the trick was to set the radius equal to 1...But how was this obvious to you? Meaning, is there a rule for when finding ratios to set r=1?

Comment: No, the volume *ratio* equals cube of radius *ratio*, so the radius  can be taken arbitrarily.

Comment: I have no Issue with @Aristarchus_ removing the "Accept" from my answer and moving it to here, though this is the Exact Same Solution (Same Cubic Equation) I gave Initially and then I added the laborious Calculations only because OP got the Calculations wrong ! Now if OP claims that there is some "trick" missing in my answer, and thus this is the "correct" answer, then OP is not having the Proper Basics and is totally muddled up !!

Comment: I apologize to @Prem for accidentally removing your original correct answer. Thank you for reminding me, and I am sorry once again for I am new to Stack Exchange and thought I could label several helpful answers as the "Correct" ones.